# I'm not able to understand how Python3 map function for list is working?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, map-function

I am trying to understand the map function on Python3. I wrote the below code:

```
for ch in map(list,["66","67","68"]):
  print (ch)
```

And I'm getting the below Output:

```
['6', '6']
['6', '7']
['6', '8']
```

Can anyone explain this in detail?

Comment: try `list("66")` - what do you get?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`map` yields the result of the transform function on a single element of the provided input iterable each time you pull a value from it. So on the first pull, it's yielding the result of `list("66")`; since `str` are iterables composed of `len` `1` `str`s (the individual characters of the string), `list("66")` produces a `list` of `'6'` and `'6'`. The next time, `list("67")` produces `['6', '7']`, and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Map receives as params a function and an iterable. So, it will iterate over the iterable and run the function for each element. That means it will run in order: `list("66"); list("67"); list("68")`
list() is a pretty versatile function in Python, it will convert your string into an array of characters that create the string. That means "66" will get ["6", "6"]. Finally, your initial list will become a generator for the above mentioned lists, thanks to ShadowRanger for pointing this out.

Additionally, you can check the [official documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) for the map function

Comment: `map` in Py3 doesn't return a new `list`, so it's not a `list` of `list`s. It's a generator of `list`s.

Comment: Yes, thinking at it, you are right. My bad, I will edit my answer.